# Giving out moderation privileges for reputation no longer makes sense with Docs.SO

Tags: discussion, documentation, privileges

When you gain reputation on SO, along with that comes privileges. The idea being that, in order to get that rep, you had to actually learn how things work on Stack Overflow.

That is now no longer the case. People are able to generate huge amounts of reputation from Docs.SO. It is trivially easy to hit rep-cap purely through changes on Docs.SO.

Do we want someone who has spent no time on Q&A to:

- Review questions/answers? 2.5 days of Docs.SO rep-capping.
- Be able to create tags? 7.5 days of Docs.SO rep-capping.
- Freely edit questions/answers? 10 days of Docs.SO rep-capping.

These are things that all should require *experience* in Q&A. But Docs.SO participation doesn't require that. So what good is reputation as a measure of this.

Something needs to be done *before* we start allowing such people free, unfettered edit access to Q&A.

Comment: Another argument in favour of a separate reputation meter for Docs, then. (Or indeed no reputation from Docs at all.)

Comment: If they don't reverse the reputation gained from the docs in the beta, which I think they won't reverse, and even if they tweak the reputation gain, there will be some damage done. Because as you show there will be *many* users who have privileges and don't know how to use them.

Comment: I suggested a 500 rep max lifetime Docs cap. And others have proposed similar or better ideas.

Comment: Rep is supposed to be a measure of how much the system can trust you to give access to tools.  Given that Docs is brand-new and just about nobody appears to have any idea how to use it properly, not experienced SO users either, it doesn't make sense to use SO rep to limit access to Docs tools.  Brutal logic ;)